# Extract file contents between given lines using perl

Tags: perl, shell, sed

I want to use only `Sed` in `Perl` to capture the file contents between 1000 and 2000 lines in a given file.
I tried the below but it didn't work,Can someone help me on this please.

```
$firstLIne="1000";
$lastline="2000";

$output=`sed -n '$firstLIne,$lastline'p sample.txt`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another pure perl solution:

```
my ($firstline, $lastline) = (1000,2000);
open my $fh, '<', 'sample.txt' or die "$!";
while(<$fh>){
  print if $. == $firstline .. $. == $lastline;
}
```

if you don't use the variables anywhere else, you can use the [special use case of `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) with constants (4<sup>th</sup> paragraph if you use constant expression they automatically get compared to `$.`):

```
while(<$fh>){
  print if 1000 .. 2000;
}
```

Here is the important part from the perldoc for the `..` operator:

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors.

**Edit** Per request, with storing the intermediate lines in a variable.

```
my ($firstline, $lastline) = (1000,2000);
my $output = '';
open my $fh, '<', 'sample.txt' or die $!;
while(<$fh>){
  $output .= $_ if $. == $firstline .. $. == $lastline;
}

print $ouput;
```

Also, if your file isn't too big (it fits completely into memory) you also can read it into a list and select the lines you're interested in:

```
my $output = join '', (<$fh>)[$firstline+1..$lastline]
```

Comment: @Hâkon: the link I provided is the perldoc page for (almost all) operators. `~` Binary inverse is only mentioned in the precedence table. The ideom `=()=`, while not strictly an operator but sometimes useful isn't mentioned there (it's useful if you want to have some expression evaluate in list context, but are only interested in the size of the result).

Comment: Thanks for the solution..how can i write the result of the print command to perl variable.

Comment: assign it? above the loop: `my $variable =''` in the loop: replace `print` with `$variable .= $_`. you might want to `chomp` first, if you aren't interested in the newlines.

Comment: my $variable ='';
while(<$fh>){
  $variable.=$_ if 1000 .. 2000;
}
does this work ?

Comment: Thank you very much...sorry i cant upvote this due to lack of enough repuation.

Comment: im new to this forum...not sure how to accept the answer though

Answer (score 3):

For comparison, to do this in Perl only, one could write:

```
my $firstLine=1000;
my $lastLine=2000;
my $fn="sample.txt";
my $output;

open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    last if $. > $lastLine;
    $output .= $_ if $. >= $firstLine;
}
close($fh);
```

Note that this will stop reading from file after line `$lastLine`.. so if the file contains 100,000 lines it will only read the first 2000 lines..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print out the lines then:

`perl -ne 'print if 1000 .. 2000'  example_data.txt`

should work.

If you want to incorporate that into a script somehow then you can "semi-slurp" the filehandle:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $filehandle, 'example_data.txt' or die $!;
my $lines_1k_to_2k ;

while (<$filehandle>)  {
  $lines_1k_to_2k .= $_ if 1000 .. 2000 ;
}

print $lines_1k_to_2k ;
```

The `.=` operator will add the lines to the string in variable `$lines_1k_to_2k` only `if` they are in the range `1000 .. 2000`